# java.sql.sqlexception: no suitable driver for (database link)

Tags: java, mysql

When I run my application I got this message (java.sql.sqlexception: no suitable driver for (database link)) 
I searched for more the 13 hours and tried more than 10 solutions so.. 
this my connection code

```
                       package khaledbayzav0.pkg1;

  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
  import java.sql.Statement;
  import javax.swing.*;

 public class MySQLconn {
 public static Connection mkmbhs(){

           try{

                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/fuchs","root","mkmbhs");
                 Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
     }
             catch(SQLException e){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

}
        return null;
   }
 }
```

and this the actions of Db (My Buttons and fields (jFrame)

```
     package khaledbayzav0.pkg1;
     import java.awt.event.* ;
     import java.awt.* ;
     import java.sql.*;
     import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
     import javax.swing.*;
     public class NewCustomers extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection con = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;


public NewCustomers() {
    initComponents();
    con = MySQLconn.mkmbhs();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    name = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    tele = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    adrs = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    sv = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    add = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "New Customer Form", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 11))); // NOI18N

    jLabel5.setText("Supervisor:");

    jLabel4.setText("Address:");

    jLabel3.setText("Telphone:");

    jLabel2.setText("Customer Name:");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jLabel5))
            .addGap(79, 79, 79)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(sv, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 301, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(adrs)
                .addComponent(tele)
                .addComponent(name))
            .addContainerGap(55, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(tele, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(adrs, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(sv, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)))
            .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    add.setText("ADD");
    add.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            addActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("BACK");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Blackadder ITC", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 0, 0));
    jLabel6.setText("Designed By Mkmbhs");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(58, 58, 58)
            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 174, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 99, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(add, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 174, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(40, 40, 40))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(230, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel6)
            .addGap(219, 219, 219))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(add)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 28, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel6)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    close();
    CustomersSelection CS = new CustomersSelection();
    CS.setVisible(true);
}                                        

private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    try {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO customerinof(CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerTelephone, CustomerSupervisor) values (?,?,?,?)";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, name.getText());
        pst.setString(2, adrs.getText());
        pst.setString(3, tele.getText());
        pst.setString(4, sv.getText());


        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Customer added to your table ");
    }
    catch (Exception e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}                                   


public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewCustomers().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton add;
private javax.swing.JTextField adrs;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JTextField name;
private javax.swing.JTextField sv;
private javax.swing.JTextField tele;
// End of variables declaration                   

private void close() {
    WindowEvent closeW = new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(closeW);
}

   }
```

Comment: You simply don't have the mysql driver jar file in your classpath. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: port is missing in getConnection statement?

Answer (score 1):

Put your **mysql driver jar** (mysql-connector.jar) in your server lib folder. This need to be present in the `classpath` for interacting with the database.

Comment: Actually I have the jar one (mysql-connector.jar)in my server
but isn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You are **not loading driver class**

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Have a look at the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

You need mysql-connector jar in class path to load above `Driver` class.
You can download it from [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)

#### Related Links

- [Connecting to MySQL Using the JDBC DriverManager Interface](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)
- [Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)